# Powershell - formatting output of body info for sending via email

Tags: email, powershell, smtp, format

I am having an issue whereby i have retrieved a list of files in a particular folder. Works fine!. I am now trying to format it on the email body.
The first to columns of data is fine but the third which is the file size (i want to right-align it) keeps coming out of whack.

I've tried an number of different formatting options as suggested on the web but nothing seems to work.

Here is the main part of the program :

```
 #Get List of files in Rejected Folder
    $files = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse| Where-Object {     !$_.PSIsContainer }) 

    #Setup eMail properties
    $From = "xxxxxx@yyyyyy.zzz"
    $To = "bbbbbbbbb"
    $Subject = "Files in TEST Reject Folder"
    $SMTPServer = "mail.nswhealth.net"
    $SMTPPort = "25"

#Setup the Body of the eMail which will include header and list of files in Rejected Folder
    $Body = "Here is a list of the files: <p>"
    $mailBody = "Filename  `t`t`t`t`t`tCreationTime `t`t`t  Size`r`n"
    $mailBody += "------------ `t`t`t`t`t`t-----------------`t`t`t  -----`r`n"

    $Count = 0  #Initialise counter
#Get list of files and append into string with 1 file per line
    foreach ($file in $files) { 
      $kb = ($([math]::Round($file.Length / 1kb)) -as [string]).ToString().Trim();
      #$kb1 = $kb + "KB"
      #$varLine1 = $file.Name + "`t" + $file.CreationTime + "{0,15}" -f $kb1 +     "`r`n"
  #Reformat Date 
      $varDate = $file.CreationTime
      $varDate1 = $varDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt")
      #$varLine1 = $file.Name + "`t" + $varDate1 + "{0,15}" -f $kb + "`r`n"
      #$varLine1 = $file.Name + "`t" + $varDate1 + "`t" + $kb + " KB" + "`r`n"
      $varLine1 = "{0,-50} {1,2} {2,-19} {3,2} {4,15} {5,3} {6,4}" -f     $file.Name, "`t", $varDate1, "`t", $kb, "KB", "`r`n"
      $mailBody += $varLine1;
      $Count++;    #increment counter
    }
#When complete list has been setup in body, add a total file counter to the end
    $mailBody += "`r`nTotal Number of Files: " + $Count

#Send 
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)
    $smtp.Send($From, $To, $Subject, $mailBody)
```

I've attached a picture of what it looks like, not sure if it shows ok.But here is a mock up of what it looks like. As you can see first 2 columns are okay, but the third is always out slightly (can't exactly mock it up as what i get on the email)

Filename                    CreationTime              Size
------------                -----------------         -----
000000AB0001.ref             10/11/2015 05:00 PM      86  KB
0113585H0000.ref             15/05/2015 03:10 PM      152  KB
0264621J0000.ref             15/05/2015 02:50 PM      125  KB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rkdv.png)

Any help would be appreciated
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to use `pre` tag to include preformatted text into your e-mail message:

```
$mailBody = -join @(
    'Here is a list of the files: <p>'
    '<pre>'
    $files|Format-Table -AutoSize `
    -Property @{Label='Filename';Expression='Name'},
              @{Expression='CreationTime';Format='dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt'},
              @{Label='Size';Expression={"$([math]::Round($_.Length / 1kb)) KB"};Alignment='right'} |
    Out-String -Width ([int]::MaxValue)
    '</pre>'
    "Total Number of Files: $($files.Count)"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. here is what is being sent in the email .             Here is a list of the files: <p><pre>
Filename                                    CreationTime          Size
--------                                    ------------          ----
000000AB-0700024-2015111016504204570001.ref 10/11/2015 05:00 PM  86 KB 0113585H-0844817-2015051515093309160000.ref 15/05/2015 03:10 PM 152 KB 0264621J-0844802-2015051514483005570000.ref 15/05/2015 02:50 PM 125 KB 
</pre>Total Number of Files: 12
There is no line break on the details just a continuous string. Other lines had line breaks.

Comment: Would it make a difference if i used send-mailmessage instead of the $smtp?

Comment: Here is a list of the files: 

Filename                                    CreationTime          Size
--------                                    ------------          ----
000000AB-0700024-2015111016504204570001.ref 10/11/2015 05:00 PM  86 KB
0113585H-0844817-2015051515093309160000.ref 15/05/2015 03:10 PM 152 KB

Comment: @AndrewH Do you have any problem with formatting, when you using my code? I am not vary well understand your comments.

Comment: hi PetSerAl,   the formatting wasn't adding linebreaks at the end of eachline with your code. When i added $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.Mailmessage($From, $To, $Subject, $mailBody.ToString())
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true, the formatting became perfect. So once again thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is right (in terms of spacing). If you'll try to use monospace font to view the message you'll see it:

```
000000AB0001.ref                                         10/11/2015 05:00 PM               186  KB
```

So set up email client to use monospace font or use markup that email client cat understand: HTML, BBCode, etc. **PetSerAl** gave a good example of HTML email where body is formatted using Format-Table cmdlet and placed inside `pre` tag.